# Why does the texture quality of my 3D object degrade when displayed with Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, vuforia

I am utilizing Vuforia in Unity to develop an AR experience. Within this project, I employ both the 'Plane Finder' and the 'Ground Plane Stage' functionalities to activate an object when the ground is detected. In the Unity editor, the texture of my 3D object appears with high quality. However, when I run the application on an Android device, the texture quality deteriorates significantly upon appearance.

I've extensively researched potential issues related to Android application settings, so I doubt that's the root cause. Nonetheless, I'm open to all suggestions. I've also updated Vuforia to its latest version to ensure compatibility, but I'm at a loss as to where the issue might lie.

The first image shows the object as it appears in the Unity editor, while the second depicts how it looks in-game.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Htp.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81SUH.jpg)

Comment: What are the compression settings on the texture for Android?

Comment: By default is "High Quality" for android is "normal"

Comment: In the Unity editor, the texture functions properly. However, when spawned by Vuforia, it appears to lose significant quality.

Comment: Does the background texture look sharp? Is it just the 3D object low quality?

Comment: Look, I've updated the question to include images that showcase how the object appears.